# Is there a answer to color specific word in python using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I should simulate ide with python and the problem is that i can't color specific words like import or def etc.
I did it with tkinter.
Is there a answer for that??
Thanks.

Comment: The text widget allows you to apply visual attributes to ranges of text. If you search this site you'll find many similar questions and answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suggest to direct embed a browser control inside your project. Then you can leverage all the existing syntax highlight solutions from web technologies. Three of the available solutions are:

1. https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython
2. https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/
3. https://pypi.org/project/tkinterweb/

You could check how to embed browser in tk for more details.